# Why Does my Navigation ICollection<T> Property holds 0 Items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a entity class `Alpha` which has an `ICollection<Beta> Betas` Navigation property. When I load items in `Alpha` and use this statement `.include(a => a.Betas)`, the number of items in the Navigation property is always 0 but there are items in the database table of `Beta` that links with `Alpha`. What am I doing wrong?

The query statement doing this is as follows;

```
var alphaList = _alphaRepository.GetAll()
                .Include(a => a.Betas)
                .ToList();
```

**EDITS**

Below are the entity Models

```
public class Alpha
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Beta> Betas { get; set; }

}

public class Beta
{
    public int BetaId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int AlphaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Alpha Alpha { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: what type is _alphaRepository?

Comment: @SimonKarlsson it's a repository of type Alpha I use in loading all items of entity type Alpha. It works well but the navigation properties don't load.

Comment: can you show the models code?

Comment: Still too many unknowns. Is this database-first/code-first? Are there any explicit mappings involved? What happens inside `GetAll` (or: can the `Include` be effective at all)? Is this the full class model or does it represent your more complex real model? There can be may reasons why `Include` doesn't work, so we need a complete picture.

Comment: @GertArnold It is code-first. What I presented is an exact representation of the model I have. (Even though I used different names). The `GetAll`does the normal select all records that you know. It has been working for me in the past. But don't know why the include doesn't work or am I suppose to initialize the ICollection property when creating the record or something? It is really confusing.

Comment: did you check the db about `1:M` relationship ? all are created fine on the db side (`PK` and `FK`) ?

Comment: @Sampath Yes. The relationships are well created in DB

Comment: Are you using some 3rd party extensions? The `TenantId` fields look suspicious.

Comment: @IvanStoev It hasn't got anything to do with the issue. That I can assure you.

Comment: Here is the point. You are **not** doing anything wrong with the shown code. I copy/pasted your model in a clean EF6.1.3 environment, tables and FK relations were created correctly and `Include` works as expected. So it must be something not shown there.

Comment: Perhaps your `GetAll` method does `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`, this causes the real query to be executed in the database. If you try to do any other database access after that (like your `Include`, or Lazy Loading stuff) you will not really hit the database but your local list. Does `GetAll` return a `IQueryable` or a `IEnumerable/ICollection`? `IQueryable` would allow you to do the `Include` with a real database trip, the other ones wouldn't. Can you include your `GetAll` code? Are you using Lazy Loading?